Бот блокирует комментарии к публикациям Telegram канала
Есть телеграм-канал с чатом. Бот модерирует чат тг-канал - удаляет комментарии с запрещенными словами. Есть проблема: иногда (т.е. не каждый раз) получается так, что при размещении публикации исчезает возможность комментирования текста публикации. Если бот отключить, то комментарии возможны, но, при старте бота, чат как бы отваливается и возможность комментирования исчезает. В чем может быть проблема кода?
Код бота элементарный:
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import config as cfg

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if message.from_user.id not in [cfg.ADMIN_ID, cfg.CHANNEL_ID, cfg.CHAT_ID]:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()

@dp.edited_message()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if message.from_user.id not in [cfg.ADMIN_ID, cfg.CHANNEL_ID, cfg.CHAT_ID]:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


А публикация содержит запрещенные слова? Вообще, возможность комментирования поста может пропасть в одном случае - если этот пост был удален из чата, который привязан к каналу для комментирования

В том и дело, что нет: если бот запущен, то на несколько секунд появляется возможность комментирования. А потом все исчезает даже вместе с комментариями, которые появляются к публикации. Причем cfg.ADMIN_ID включает id канала, чата и админа.

я вижу только сравнение с id пользователя, который отправил сообщение. никакого канал, чата нет

if str(message.from_user.id) not in [cfg.ADMIN_ID, cfg.CHANNEL_ID, cfg.CHAT_ID]:

Если по id пользователь не админ, то его сообщения модерируются. Если смотреть по id, то id канала и чата разные. Если владелец канала пишет что-то в чате или в чат попадает публикация канала, то у админа отражается id чата

А вы вообще смотрели какой апдейт приходит боту, когда пост пересылается в группу из канала? Никакого from_user.id там нет. Есть message.from.id, и указан там id бота телеграм 777000

Нет, апдейты не смотрел, полагал, что . Подскажите, как это сделать

Останавливаем бот, публикуем пост, ждем, когда он появится в группе для комментариев, открываем ссылку https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/getUpdates (токен указать свой). И смотрим json. Вообще, в предыдущем комментарии я указал, что нужно делать. Ваша проверка не подойдет для пересланного поста в группу для комментариев - там нет ни одного проверяемого ID

Немного переписал код, но проблема осталась, разве что не каждый раз теперь пропадают комментарии. from_user.id нужен, чтобы публикации и комменты админа никак не модерировались

По ссылке  ссылку api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/… (токен указал свой), содержание файла таково:
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Ошибка в токене

Да, получилось. Channel_id и Chat_id определяются правильно, они у меня в списке исключений, но комменты все равно исчезают

Верно-то верно. Только пересылаются посты не с вашими chat_id, а указан chat_id служебного бота телеграм, 777000, кажется такой он

Когда пост пересылается из канала в привязанную группу для комментариев, у объекта message есть атрибут is_automatic_forward.

Optional. True, if the message is a channel post that was
automatically forwarded to the connected discussion group

Проверяйте его наличие, примерно так:
@dp.message()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if message.from_user.id not in [cfg.ADMIN_ID, cfg.CHANNEL_ID, cfg.CHAT_ID] or message.is_automatic_forward!=True:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()

Добавьте проверку message.is_automatic_forward!=True в другие хендлеры.
А вообще, объедините, для чего городить одно и тоже?
@dp.message()
@dp.edited_message()
async def echo_message(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if message.from_user.id not in [cfg.ADMIN_ID, cfg.CHANNEL_ID, cfg.CHAT_ID] or message.is_automatic_forward!=True:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()


Некоторые комментаторы пытаются обходить модерацию: публикуют нормальный комментарий, а затем редактируют его заменяя некоторые слова на запрещенные. Делал это с помощью двух разных хэндлеров.

Что касается атрибута message.is_automatic_forward, то комментарии от канала отваливались не каждый раз, могло появиться 5-10 публикаций и все ок. А затем публикация со ссылкой и комментирование отваливалось через 20 - 25 секунд после публикации. Причем не важно, были комментарии или нет.

@Andrey две корутины вместе, хендлер будет срабатывать и на новое сообщение и на редактирование. Комментарии могут пропасть только в случае, если пересланный пост из канала был удален из группы. Вы это проверили? Посты на месте, когда пропали комментарии? Смотрите логи группы

Есть канал и привязанный к нему чат. Проблема была в том, что не всегда, но периодически, при размещении публикации пропадала возможность ее комментирования. Причем появлялись комментарии, но через 20 сек внизу публикации пропадала вкладка "комментировать", причем вместо со всеми оставленными к публикации комментариями. Чат работал по-прежнему и в чате публикации не удалялись. Приходилось отключать бот, но затем, после включения бота, все комменты вновь пропадали. После добавления в код message.is_automatic_forward все ок. Спасибо!

Извините за вопрос, мало опыта. Но как  посмотреть логи группы?

@Andrey Когда в группе жмете на карандашик, в самом низу будет Недавние действия. Вот там и есть логи

Возможно, что это глюк Телеграм, но сегодня снова чат отвалился)

Заметил, что если в публикации владельца канала есть слова из списка запрещенных, то комментарии отваливаются сразу. Или через некоторое время после редактирования публикации - добавлением запрещенных слов. Видимо ошибка в коде исключающем id админа из модерации

@Andrey время, за которое пропадают комментарии не так важно. Оно вообще зависит от самого телеграм - пока обновления пройдут, тогда и комментарии пропадут у поста

Нашел ошибку в строке кода с условным оператором, исключающим модерацию для публикаций:
if not message.is_automatic_forward:

Комментарии от канала теперь не отваливаются, но исключить модерацию комментариев админа в чате не получается.
Условие на работает и функция удаления комментариев не запускается.
if not message.is_automatic_forward and message.from_user.id not in ADMIN_ID:
print(message.is_automatic_forward, message.from_user.id, cfg.ADMIN_ID)
Принт дает None и два непонятных мне int:
INFO:aiogram.event: Update id=330***** is handled. Duration 16 ms by bot id=582*****
None 108**** 128*****
